unable to connect to repo.anaconda.com
Im trying to install anaconda on a company laptop, Ive installed it on other computers without problems...
I navigate to https://www.anaconda.com/download, give my email address and click the submit button, it's trying to connect to repo.anaconda.com but it never succeeds. I get this error in firefox: secure connection failed, windows edge gives: can't reach this page, the connection was reset. It doesn't make any difference if I sign into my anaconda account.
Could it be something to do with the firewall settings? I can navigate the rest of the website without issues. I don't get any website forbidden messages, I'd be surprised if the website was blocked... Using Ubuntu on windows (WSL) I have the same problem.
$ curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:05:00 --:--:--     0
curl: (28) SSL connection timeout

Any ideas?

Could you provide more details? e.g. OS version? Browser? Can you open https://repo.anaconda.com? What happens when you directly enter https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64.exe in your browser? Which error do you get in the Developer Tools of your browser?

I can't access any address starting with https://repo.anaconda.com, using browsers firefox (v130), edge(v129), chrome. When I try to I get just a blank screen for several minutes then the message:
Secure Connection Failed
An error occurred during a connection to repo.anaconda.com. PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR
Error code: PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR
Im on a thinkpad laptop (recent <2yrs) with windows 11 enterprise. It must be a firewall or something. I can access the site immediately from my phone...

Ok problem resolved, the site is blocked by our IT...
